# change value of bars with arrow key down

Tags: javascript, css, keydown

hee there,

I have made bars in my css, now i wrote code so when you push the arrow key down, you see the values are changing of the bars(it's going up). Now i want when you hold the arrow key down the values are changing and when you release the arrow key down, the bars stops(with going up) at the point that you release the button..... Has anyone an idea how?

this is my code now injavascript

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 40){
    changeIdValue("balklongwaarde", "60px");
};
}
```

And this is what the bar is like in my css

```
/*bar for lungs*/
#balklongwaarde{
height: 150px;
width: 40px;
border: 1px solid #2e9afe;
background: #2e9afe;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 200px;
margin-left: 200px;
}
```

This is also my animation already

```
* {
-webkit-transition:1s 0s all ease;
   -moz-transition:1s 0s all ease;
     -o-transition:1s 0s all ease;
        transition:1s 0s all ease;
```

Comment: it's still unclear on the function `changeIdValue`, normally this kind of increasing/decreasing value should have some minimum and maximum values to take into consideration.

Comment: the animation stops at 60px

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N84E2/

Comment: If you need to allow user to adjust the value by `1`, you should not use `transition` in this case, transition works best when the step (between 2 keydown strokes) is larger than 1, also the `transition-timing-function` should be `linear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setInterval to simulate a key pressed, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N84E2/2/) and example

```
var intervalID;
//through arrow down values are changing//
window.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
        if(typeof intervalID == 'undefined') {
            intervalID = window.setInterval(changeIdValue, 10);       
        }

    };
}
```